# Where can I ask questions regarding theoretical concepts?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Specifically, I'm interested in where to ask questions on parallel processing theory and information theory.

Comment: pls be specific

Answer (score 3):

[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) (Note: still in Beta)

> question and answer site for students, researchers and practitioners
>   of computer science